# MUI Theming color (primary > light). Could not understand the usage of light color property

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to understand the theming of MUI. There is a section dedicated to theming. I understand that I can change the theme.
My question is:

- There are three colors I can define inside primary color, namely: `main`, `dark` and `light`. I could not figure out what `light` color property inside of `primary` does.

This link shows the color used by MUI
`https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/`. If you expand `palette > primary`. There is `light` color property but I could not see how or where it is used. I tried on `button` but that color does not appear on any state(hover, active) of `button`

NOTE: I don't believe its related to dark and light theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not related to the light/dark theme, the `mode` property is responsible for this.

`pallete -> mode: 'light'/'dark'` - switching between the modes.

The `pallete -> main -> light` is just a color which you can configure and use through ypur app. But it's not only the `main` property, in pallete you can see from the docs that there are a lot of different theming use cases like `success`, `secondary`, `info`, etc., and all of them have the `light` property. So you can use the light and dark variants of a certain color. The use cases are many and differ.

Ref to mui pallete docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

Answer (score 0):

@Dobromir Kirov, Thanks for the answer. I believe all the colors(main, light, dark) are not used on the every component. The link below demonstrates the example of usage:

`https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-pine-3wpr8p?file=/demo.js`

In the example I can see:

1. The `main` and `dark` color of `success` is used on the `Button`.
2. The `light` color is of the `success` is used on the `Alert`.

Even though I have defined all three colors (`main`, `dark`, `light`). It depends on the component.